# How to pass variable list in ViewBag

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewbag

I am working on a project I just need to grab data from two tables and I want to use LINQ Query to fetch data.

Inside my Controller:

```
var Parameters = (from test in _db.tblAddTests
               join par in _db.tblParameters on test.AddTestId equals 
               par.TestId
               where par.ParameterDatatype == 3
               select new
               {
                ParameterId = par.ParameterId, 
                ParameterName = par.ParameterName,
                TestName = test.TestName
                }
            ).ToList();
ViewBag.Parameters = Parameters;
```

And I want to use this Parameters in my razor as:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Parameters)
{
    <option value="@item.ParameterId">@item.ParameterName - @item.TestName</option>
}
```

It is currently giving me error that object as no definition for ParameterId.
Although I have tried debugging and item is getting values as well but I am not sure how to display them,

Here is screen shot of values I am getting
Values in item variable:
[image: Values in item variable]

Also Here is Screen shot of the error:

[image: Error]

Comment: How about a simple typecast?

Comment: I tried to convert it in ArrayList like this 
    @{
         var list = ViewBag.Parameters as ArrayList;
       }

Comment: Your code is a really bad idea - no strong typed model binding, no client side validation, the selected item, will be lost if returning the view etc etc. Use use the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method to generate your `<select>` and pass a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the view

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stephen, But I don't want to use that at all because this is just an example I have to use multiple models later on so they will create a fuss for me :p

Answer (score 4):

You are using an anonymous type. It wouldn't work in this case. Either use a known type or dynamic. ie:

```
var Parameters = (from test in _db.tblAddTests
               join par in _db.tblParameters on test.AddTestId equals 
               par.TestId
               where par.ParameterDatatype == 3
               select new ParamsClass
               {
                ParameterId = par.ParameterId, 
                ParameterName = par.ParameterName,
                TestName = test.TestName
                }
            ).ToList();
ViewBag.Parameters = Parameters;

public class ParamsClass
{
  public int ParameterId {get; set;}
  public string ParameterName {get; set;}  
  public string TestName {get; set;}
}
```

In view:

```
@foreach (ParamsClass item in ViewBag.Parameters)
{
    <option value="@item.ParameterId">@item.ParameterName - @item.TestName</option>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much -Cetin Basoz

Answer (score 3):

You can make a new class in your controller:

```
public class Params
{
public int ParameterId {get; set;}
public string ParameterName {get; set;}  
public string TestName {get; set;}
}
```

In View 
You can use it like this

```
@{
var items = (Params)ViewBag.Parameters;
}
@foreach(var item in items){
your code for html....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ishfaq I really Got the Answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
{
public int ID{get; set;}
public string Name{get; set;}  
}
```

Use this syntax in your CSHTML:

```
@{
var items = (Params)ViewBag.Parameters;
}
@foreach(var item in items){
//body
}
```